# How to get all keys from STL hash_map?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

Is there any way to get all keys from an STL hash_map? Or I have to use something like set or hash_set to record them before insertion?

Comment: Note that in all proposed solutions the keys are unordered (which is fine, why order if there is no need?) If you need them ordered you will need to `sort` the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
hash_map<string, void *> hashMap;

vector<string> keys;
keys.reserve(hashMap.size());

for (hash_map<string, void *>::iterator iter = hashMap.begin(); 
                                        iter != hashMap.end(); 
                                        ++iter)
{
    keys.push_back(iter->first);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "iter.first"

Answer (score 4):

Simply iterate over the `hash_map`; for each iteration, `iter->first` is the key.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Igor Oks' answer:

```
hash_map<string, void *> hashMap;

vector<string> keys;
keys.reserve(hashMap.size());

transform(hashMap.begin(), hashMap.end(), back_inserter(keys),
    select1st<hash_map<string, void*>::value_type>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to iterate through the hash_map, and extract the first element from the pair pointed by current iterator value (the first element of the pair is in fact a key).

```
// Assuming that hm is an instance of hash_map:
for (auto it = hm.begin(); it != hm.end(); ++it) // for each item in the hash map:
{
    // it->first is current key
    // ... you can push_back it to a vector<Key> or do whatever you want
}
```

This is a possible function to extract keys from a hash_map to a vector:

```
template <typename Key, typename Type, typename Traits, typename Allocator>
vector<Key> extract_keys(const hash_map<Key, Type, Traits, Allocator> & hm)
{
    vector<Key> keys;

    // If C++11 'auto' is not available in your C++ compiler, use:
    // 
    //   typename hash_map<Key, Type, Traits, Allocator>::const_iterator it;
    //   for (it = hm.begin(); ...)
    //
    for (auto it = hm.begin(); it != hm.end(); ++it)
    {
        keys.push_back(it->first);
    }

    return keys;        
}
```